# Timeout error when deploying applications to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-app-engine-python, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to execute a deployment to Google App Engine (flexible environment) via Bitbucket Pipelines. The error I am experiencing is as follows:

**Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...⠹DEBUG: Operation [apps/[PROJECT ID]/operations/{}] not complete. Waiting to retry.**

This message continues to print until it finally times out and I receive the following error:

**ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.**

This appears to be a fairly recent issue. A couple of weeks ago, this deployment (with the same configurations) was working just fine.

Below is the app.yaml file that i am trying to deploy via gcloud app deploy:

```
runtime: python
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 60000
env: flex 
threadsafe: true

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 4
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.75

runtime_config:
python_version: 2
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please kindly check this solution from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347959/bitbucket-pipelines-deploy-to-gcloud-appengine-causes-13-an-internal-error-occ). The original poster resolved his issue.

Answer (score -1):

This issue was answered in a Public Issue Tracker found here: [1]. There, you can find a list of common causes for your issue such as service accounts missing permissions which you can fix on the Cloud Console [2], or by turning off and back on the API/service affected.

[1] Public Issue Tracker with same issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/119488754#comment3

[2] Granting roles to service accounts: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts